# How to fix a display issue in a multiple line graph. The svg.append("path") is not displaying anything

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

Im trying to create a multiline graph for my angular web app to visualise some data that will add lines according to the items in the data variable. As i'm trying to append the path line in the svg element i can't manage to display it. Right now only the two axes are displayed correctly.

```
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(2000, 0, 0), new Date(2017, 0, 0)]).range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    var svg = d3.select(this.htmlElement).append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")).ticks(d3.timeYear, 1));

    // Add the Y Axis 
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

    // define the line
    var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return d.value;
      });

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr('d', line(d.series))
        .attr('stroke', 'blue')
        .attr('stroke-width', 2)
        .attr('fill', 'none');
    });
```

the structure of the data is

```
var data = [{
      "key": "Germany",
      "series": [
        {
          "a": "Germany",
          "name": "2010",
          "value": 0.2
        },
        {
          "a": "Germany",
          "name": "2011",
          "value": 0.5
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "key": "uk",
      "series": [
        {
          "a":"uk",
          "name": "2010",
          "value": 0.3
        },
        {
          "a":"uk",
          "name": "2011",
          "value": 0.6
        }
      ]
    }];
```

i guess that the problem lies on the data.foreach loop but i can't manage to find it.

Comment: You are not using your scales in the line generator. I.e. `.x(function(d) { return d.name; })` should be `.x(function(d) { return x(d.name); })` instead (likewise for the `.y()` part).

Comment: In addition to @matthias.rocks corrections, you also aren't setting a `.domain` on your y-scale.

Comment: Wait, you also need to convert the year stored in the `name` properties, otherwise D3's scaleTime will interpret it as a timestamp (i.e. a few seconds after epoch). Something like `.x(function(d) { return x(new Date(d.name, 0)); })` should work.

Comment: @Mark True indeed - nice catch.

Comment: yes thank you, these were the issues, i posted the working code as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the comments above the working code can be seen below

```
      var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(2000, 0, 0), new Date(2017, 0, 0)]).range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,1]).range([height, 0]);

    var svg = d3.select(this.htmlElement).append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")).ticks(d3.timeYear, 1));

    // Add the Y Axis 
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

    // define the line
    var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { 
        return x(new Date(d.name, 0)); 
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
      });

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr('d', line(d.series))
        .attr('stroke', 'blue')
        .attr('stroke-width', 2)
        .attr('fill', 'none');
    });
```